# Schwarz Counter and variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

For people who never heard of "Schwarz Counter", please refer to [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) wikibook page.

I'm trying to implement this idiom with C++11 template, everything works fine except when the template argument ISN'T default constructible. Here is my implementation: (See the code comments for the question)

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Single {
public:
    static T& get() {
        return reinterpret_cast<T&>(instance.storage);
    }

private:
    struct Instance {
        enum { kSize = sizeof(T), kAlign = std::alignment_of<T>::value };

        int counter;
        typename std::aligned_storage<kSize, kAlign>::type storage;

        template<typename... Arg>
        Instance(Arg&&... param) {
            if (counter++ == 0) {
                new (&storage) T(param...);
            }
        }

        ~Instance() {
            if (--counter == 0) {
                reinterpret_cast<T&>(storage).~T();
            }
        }
    };

    static Instance instance;
};

// The following won't compile if T isn't default constructible.
// I want to get rid of the definition in this case, and let the
// users of this template to provide their own definitions.
// I'd like to keep the it when T is default constructible, because
// most of the time T is (according to my experience, most global 
// objects are constructed without arguments, singletons are
// essentially global objects).
//
// So, basically I want something like this:
// #if std::is_default_constructible<T>::value
//     template<typename T>
//     ...;
// #endif
// Could this be done in C++11 ? If not, how about C++14 ?
template<typename T>
typename Single<T>::Instance Single<T>::instance;
```

BTW, define a singleton with this template is very simple if the class is default constructible, for example:

```js
class Y {
    friend class Single<Y>;
    Y(int, int) { std::cout << "Y()\n"; }
    ~Y() { std::cout << "~Y()\n"; }
};

class X {
    friend class Single<X>;
    X() { std::cout << "X()\n"; }
    ~X() { std::cout << "~X()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    auto& x = Single<X>::get();
    // auto& g = Single<Y>::get(); // oops
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two classes.  One for default constructable T, another for not.

Dispatch your main implementation to only use the default constructable instance iff it is default constructable.

```
template<class T,class=void>
struct WhichSingle {
  using type=Single<T>;
};
template<class T>
struct WhichSingle<T,typename std::enable_if<
  !std::is_default_constructible<T>::value
>::type> {
  using type=SingleNoDefault<T>;
};

template<class X>
using Bob = typename WhichSignle<X>::type;
```

and `Bob<X>` is either `Single` or `SingleNoDefault`.

Better names, and work to reduce duplication, can be done, but that is just grunt work.

Comment: @user416983 put the static variable in its own class, have it use other stuff?  Everything else is common, except that static variable, and glue to "see" the common stuff.